# Reading a CSV file to create 10 x 10 px pngs based on the rgb values in the CSV document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color, png

First time posting after trying to figure out a solution that would save me time with a project I'm doing. 
I Have this idea of using a CSV document to generate colour patches needed for another program. being a designer I don't have much experience with scripts or programming except the basic java.

The program I want to make needs to do as follows :
Collum 1 - Filename to save. 
Collum 3 - file identifier to save.
Example of this is :

Name | id | Type

|dave | 1  | Default

Output would be 
Dave_Default.png

Next id need it to read the values of columns 4,5,6 as rgb values :
Example :

Name | id | Type    | R | G | B |

| dave | 1  | Default |187|112|0  |

then take those values and generate a 10 x 10-pixel block in that colour value. Save the 10x10px square as a .png with the file name as stated before then move on to the next one on the rows.

End result is :
Dave_Default.png - Colour png swatch

I'm sure this is a lot to ask but any help would be amazing as it would save hours and hours of work manually inputting the RGB values into photoshop and exporting a png one at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Scripting is relatively simple in Photoshop and you can easily scrap bits of code from  google. Obviously any proficiency in Javascript would save you a lot of time, so I'd recommend to spend an hour and take a course on basics of JS on any code learning web academy.

Next you'll need to read your csv: [the first google link will show you how](https://www.joshwright.com/tips/reading-and-writing-text-files-from-photoshop-scripts).

From this file you'll get a bunch of strings, say `dave,1,Default,187,112,0`, so you'll make an array of them first with `string.split(',')`. This will give you an array `[dave,1,Default,187,112,0]` so you could access the color values as `arr[3]`, `arr[4]` and `arr[5]`. Voilà — you have a bunch of data to work with.

Next for each data string you'll need to create a new document. Let's see what [Photoshop Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2019.pdf) says about this: it seems like there's exactly what you need on page 104: `documents` (a collection of opened documents) has a method `.add`, so you can do `documents.add(new UnitValue(10, 'px'),new UnitValue(10, 'px'));`

Now you'll want to fill it with color. First you need to set a color to fill with, there's a `SolidColor` object in Photoshop to contain color information and `.fill()` method of `selection` object to fill a selection with color. So you first define the color, select all, fill with color. And you can use the values you have already for this:

```
var newColor = new SolidColor;
newColor.rgb.red = arr[3];
newColor.rgb.green = arr[4];
newColor.rgb.blue = arr[5];
app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
app.activeDocument.selection.fill(newColor);
app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();
```

Almost done, you only need to save the file. Once again, [google to the rescue](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1511528).

And that's it.

Comment: You Legend ! Thanks my google fu  was not so strong today !